# How to open a shell within Statefulset POD in Kubernetes using namespace

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

When it comes to PODS with:

```
kind: Deployment
```

the command has a following format:

```
kubectl exec -it [# POD_NAME #] -- sh
```

I am not sure how to accomplish the same, when I do have PODs defined using:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Statefulset` number of pods will be created defined in `spec.replicas`. The Pods' names take the form `<statefulset name>-<ordinal index>`. If your StatefulSet has two replicas, it creates two Pods, **`<statefulset-name>-0`** and **`<statefulset-name>-1`**

You can exec

```
$ kubectl exec -it **<statefulset name>-<ordinal index>** -- sh
```

You can see the created pod by your satefulset using

```
kubectl get pods -l <label in spec.template.metadata.labels>
```

More details [click](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#pods-in-a-statefulset)

Answer (score 1):

It should be same because both `StatefulSet` and `Deployment` creates pod at the end.

```
kubectl exec -it podname -n namespacename -- sh
```